# Why does UIMap Coded UI Test Builder "Hang"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to create some coded UI tests by using the "UIMap - Coded UI Test Builder" with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. We are developing a web application. I'm able to run the builder (recorder) but when I try to pause or create source code I get a "Please wait..." message that never goes away. The progress bar goes from left to right continuously.

[image]

I looked through the event view and I don't see any error logs that appear to match this.

Comment: I've had this issue too, many times. I eventually need to kill the process and retry. I don't think it has anything to do with the technology you're working with and everything to do with a buggy recorder. No solutions can be found.

Comment: Did you ever make any progress with this? Seems to be a lot of people with this issue, but with no fix. I've tried disabling all my extensions, starting VS in safe mode and repairing my VS installation, but with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Think I've figured this out.
I had Chrome open, then proceeded to test against IE by running my web project.
I stopped Chrome and for my tests I opened a new IE window, navigated to my page, did my test actions and the test saved successfully after this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, it did not. Any other ideas? Guess programming (100% code) will do!